# How to create a scattered td columns in different positions on the table

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a html table with the column having placed in different places of the table. A table with 10 record having 15 td columns in different places.I am looking for the help to bring this layout in my code.[image]. I have attached my layout as png format. Here is my code

```
<table id = "empTable">    
@{
    foreach (var item in Model.builds) {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Build1</td>
        <td>@item.Build2</td>
        <td>@item.Build3</td>
        <td>@item.Build4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@item.Build5</td>
        <td>@item.Build6</td>
        <td>@item.Build7</td>            
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>@item.Build8</td>
        <td>@item.Build9</td>
        <td>@item.Build10</td>             
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@item.Build11</td>
        <td>@item.Build12</td>
        <td>@item.Build13</td> 
        <td>@item.Build14</td>
    </tr>
    
}
<table>
```

Comment: Yes , I have corrected my given code with 4 rows in a page

Comment: I think that if you want to achieve the effect in the picture, then you need to set the corresponding css style for each `td`, and you need to reserve the cell position for those places without content filling when creating table.